# Create video file from images in Android

Tags: android, image-processing

I am reading found many articles and info about creating video from sequence of images. They all recommend to use ffmpeg. The thing is that this pretty complicated. There is simple way to do this without ffmpeg? I need that the result video will be readable to regular video player on the device.

Comment: Stuck with same problem Hey Dim, Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by complicated. If you are not very comfortable with native layer then you might use [javaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/). It provides java wrapper for ffmpeg among other open source library and works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, you want to make use of the `Movie`. The reference is here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html

And, a sample example is here:

https://code.google.com/p/animated-gifs-in-android/

Comment: It does not create a file, which can be read by Movie Players. That is the requirement as per OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JCodec](http://jcodec.org/) library.
It now supports android too.
You need to download the library and add it in your project.
here is an example of using the library:

```
SequenceEncoder se = null;

        try {
            se = new SequenceEncoder(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "jcodec_enc.mp4"));
            File[] files = yourDirectory.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0;i<files.length; i++) {
                if (!files[i].exists())
                    break;
                Bitmap frame = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[i]
                        .getAbsolutePath());
                se.encodeImage(frame);

            }
            se.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO", e);
        }
```